# Why does my recorder not allow me to move the window while recording?

Tags: c#

I am making a recorder that records a specific window the user chooses. While I am recording, the program forces the window to be active all the time. That means that I can not move the window at all or even to change the size of the window. I was not able to stop the recording. Is there a way to fix that?

**Combobox code**:

```
private void Handlebox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Handlebox.SelectedIndex == -1) return;
        handle_name = Handlebox.SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

**The way I add all the processes in the combobox:**

```
foreach (Process process in processlist)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(process.MainWindowTitle))
    {
        Handlebox.Items.Add(process.ProcessName);
    }
}
```

**The script that the whole recording takes place:**

```
// Record video:
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Rect
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private const int SW_RESTORE = 9;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref Rect rect);

public Bitmap CaptureApplication(string procName)
{
    Process proc;

    // Cater for cases when the process can't be located.
    try
    {
        proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName)[0];
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfRangeException e)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // You need to focus on the application
    SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
    ShowWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, SW_RESTORE);

    // Delay
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    Rect rect = new Rect();
    IntPtr error = GetWindowRect(proc.MainWindowHandle, ref rect);

    // sometimes it gives error.
    while (error == (IntPtr)0)
    {
        error = GetWindowRect(proc.MainWindowHandle, ref rect);
    }

    int width = rect.right - rect.left;
    int height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics.FromImage(bmp).CopyFromScreen(rect.left,rect.top,0,0,new Size(width, height),CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

    return bmp;
}

public void RecordVideo()
{
    // Keep track of time:
    watch.Start();

    // Save screenshot:
    string name = tempPath + "//screenshot-" + fileCount + ".png";
    CaptureApplication(handle_name).Save(name, ImageFormat.Png);
    inputImageSequence.Add(name);
    fileCount++;

    // Dispose of bitmap:
    CaptureApplication(handle_name).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated to your question, but CaptureApplication is being called twice, each time with a chained member call against the returned object - you will want to change that to `using(var image = CaptureApplication (handle_name)) { }`, and inside that scope you do `image.Save` (the `using` scope ensures proper disposal so you don't need to do `image.Dispose()` explicitly). That said saving each individual frame image as a PNG is likely very costly; not clear where `inputImageSequence` is coming from but it looks like some `List<string>` with filenames...

Comment: I failed to properly explain my concern: you're capturing every frame twice, and only disposing one of the two bitmaps returned (and the bitmap that gets disposed isn't the bitmap you saved to disk)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I believe you mean to add at the RecordVideo() function the ```using(var image = CaptureApplication (handle_name)) { }``` and inside the brackets I should add the other code?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to capture once and grab the returned bitmap, save it, then dispose it. If you invoke the capture once then save, then invoke it again and dispose, you haven't disposed the first returned object (which is now inaccessible), and you haven't saved the second one.

Comment: Also consider making the I/O work asynchronous, and introduce a buffer so you can capture a frame or two (or more!) while a frame is being persisted to disk. Basically you want to decouple the capturing from the I/O work.... but none of this relates directly to the question you asked =)

Comment: Possible that as far as Windows is concerned, a window isn't considered active when it is being moved or resized. Remember a few years ago Windows would be drawing a rectangle instead of repainting the window while you moved/resized it. Kind of low-level stuff but perhaps you could subclass the window to hook into its Win32 message pump and find out exactly what's going on here.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Ok, one think at the time. Lets talk about the window. Is there a way to make it keep recording while its moved or at least if it's not the active window? If there is a way could you show me?

Comment: It could be interesting to [subclass](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/blob/next/Rubberduck.VBEEditor/WindowsApi/SubclassingWindow.cs) the app window to peek at the WM messages it receives, and get it's screen coordinates from there. Does GetWindowRect fail when you move or resize the window? Why still capture an invalid rect then? And then process the invalid frame like nothing happened? If you skip these frames does it resume with the post-move/resize state?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I am really not experienced in this... Could you take my code and do that if it's not something that needs huge amount of time? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon or at least to walk me through this if its possible.